# how to reset the gps in android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

Is there any way to reset GPS in android ?
please help.
I test some below code but not sure its work or not.

For Reset

Locationmanager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"delete_aiding_data", null);

For download GPS data

public static void downloadGPSXtra(Context context){

```
 LocationManager locationmanager1 = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 locationmanager1.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
 locationmanager1.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);

    }
```

and add the permission statements in android menifest.

"ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"

Comment: What is `resetting a gps`?

Comment: Moreover, what makes you think that all Android devices equipped with GPS will necessarily honor those particular "extra commands"?

Comment: Could you explain your overall goal, i.e. *why* you're trying to do this? There might be better ways.

Comment: I'm developing taxi tracking app.I have some complains from taxi drivers about distance ,when I tracking them their path going wrong. reset gps is one solution. Actually I want to access the GPS chip in android,is there any solution suggest me thanks @runDOSrun

Answer (score 3):

Android Location Manger uses multiple sources for location

Data Network (coarse location upto city level using IP geolocation)

Network provider (coarse location upto 100 meters using cell towers)

GNSS(Fine upto 3 meters using GPS / GLONASS / GALILEO  on GNSS chip)

Location Manager is encapsulation of hardware,you cannot access the chip. 
GNSS chips lose tracking of satellites in urban areas due to obstacles very often. Using multiple sources helps android keep track of location even when tracking from satellites is lost.

locationmanager1.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationmanager1.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);

Here you are downloading a-gps data
and synchronising GPS time.

What you are doing is force loading a-GPS data.Without a-Gps data the time to get First-Fix for a chip ranges from 3-20 minutes. With a-Gps it can be reduced to a matter of 32 seconds.

[There are some apps which need rooting , which can change the a-gps loading locations]

Location Manager heavily depends upon 'last know best location'. So what you are doing is right  and it should work in improving the accuracy to certain extent. Depending upon the device you can see the results.

On the hardware level there is a minimum of 3 meters error( can range upto 50 meters) at a given location, that should be taken into consideration when distance is calculated.